# How to find arXiv articles

Tags: webservices

I found at Twitter that is possible to search for arXiv articles with *Mathematica*, e.g. the following code:

```
arXiv = ServiceConnect["ArXiv"];
articles = arXiv["Search", {"Query" -> "Mathematica"}];
articles[All, {"URL", "Title"}]
```

gives as result:

[image]

My question is:

1. How can I specify the time range in between the articles were published?
2. Is it possible to combine search keywords with binary operators (AND, OR, etc.)?

**UPDATE:**

To my second question:

```
articles = 
  arXiv["Search", {"Query" -> {"Title" -> {"Mathematica" | "Solving"}}}];
```

searches for all articles containing `"Mathematica" OR "Solving"` in `"Title"`

```
articles = 
  arXiv["Search", {"Query" -> {"Title" -> {"Mathematica", "Solving"}}}];
```

searches for all articles containing `"Mathematica" AND "Solving"` in `"Title"`

Comment: Interesting that you only get 10 results - on the ArXiv web page there are more than 1000 hits - ah one needs a `, MaxItems -> 250` or some such.

Comment: Just use google :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on the previous answer you can restrict by date pretty trivially using Mathematica:

```
arXiv = ServiceConnect["ArXiv"];
articles = arXiv["Search", {
    "Query" -> "Mathematica",
    "MaxItems" -> 1000, 
    "SortBy" -> "DateSubmitted"}];

selectFromRange[articles_, dmin_, dmax_] :=

 With[{min = DateObject@Normal@dmin, max = DateObject@Normal@dmax},
  articles[Select[min < #Published < max &]]
  ];

selectFromRange[articles, DateObject@Today[{"Year"}], Today]
```

Looking through the [API documentation](https://arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual) there doesn't seem to be a way to restrict *within* an API call and so any processing by date would have to be done after the fact anyway.

Comment: That could be shortened a fair bit: `articles[Select[#Updated ~Between~ {DateObject[{2016, 12, 20}], Today} &]]`.

Comment: I figured for generality I'd leave the conversion of an arbitrary `DateObject` to it's most expanded form. Size comparisons for `DateObjects` with the different degrees of specificity, e.g., `DateObject[{2016, 12}]` and `DateObject[{2016, 12, 10}]` don't evaluate and the `Normal` scheme gets them to (by expanding to a `DateList`. One error though is that `Today["Year"]` should be `DateObject@Today[{"Year"}]`.

Comment: Huh. This works, tho: `articles[Select[#Published ~Between~ {DateObject[{2016, 10}], DateObject[{2016, 12}]} &]]`

Comment: That should select anything from Dec 11 2016. Try: `Between[DateObject[{2016, 12, 10}], {DateObject[{2016, 10}], 
  DateObject[{2016, 12}]}]` to see what I mean. You get `DateObject[{2016, 12, 10}] <= DateObject[{2016, 12}]` as a return.

Answer (score 19):

Something like this:

```
arXiv = ServiceConnect["ArXiv"];

articles = 
  arXiv["Search", {"Query" -> {"Abstract" -> {"Eigenvalues", 
        "Mathematica"}}, MaxItems -> 25, "SortBy" -> "DateSubmitted"}];
articles[All, {"URL", "Title", "Published"}]
```

Looking at the help page has more info: [ArXiv](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/ArXiv.html)

Comment: This successfully sorts the results by date, but how do you restrict results to be between a date range, as requested by the OP?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the questions ... the rest I found also in the help.